# Change Value of Linq Grouping

Tags: c#, linq, tuples, grouping

I have the following Grouping:

```
IGrouping<string, Tuple<IFileInfo, XDocument>>
```

I'd like to convert this to the simplified grouping of just:

```
IGrouping<string, XDocument>
```

What's the simplest way to do this?

Additional information:

The initial group was created from a list of

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<IFileInfo, XDocument>> myList
```

by calling

```
myList.GroupBy(x => GetSomePropertyToGroupBy(x.Item2));
```

To return a list of

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Tuple<IFileInfo, XDocument>>>
```

It's the IGrouping> aspect of this list that I want to filter down to just contain the XDocument from the Tuple, not the IFileInfo.

Comment: Can you at least show how you get to the first grouping?

Comment: Pleas share your [mcve].

Comment: `IGrouping` does not have any publicly accessible implementation in the framework so the "simplest way to do this" (not impacting performance) is probably to create your own `IGrouping` implementation

Comment: Do you want to convert a single IGrouping or an IEnumerable<IGrouping<>>?

Comment: Do you actuallyy have a `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Tuple<IFileInfo, XDocument>>>`?

Comment: Yes. It's a list of documents split by an aspect of the XDocument and each document has an associated FileInfo.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your comment, you can use this [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.110).aspx) overload to select the key and the element:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, XDocument>> groups = 
    myList.GroupBy(
        x => GetSomePropertyToGroupBy(x.Item2),
        x => x.Item2);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to change the original grouping as it's used elsewhere. I just need to drop the FileInfo part of the tuple when passing the group around.

Comment: If you don't want to implement IGrouping yourself you'd need to use SelectMany to get all the elements and group again using my last code or this GroupBy

Comment: @jimbo Then maybe you can use something that doesn't use IGrouping like `IEnumerable<Tuple<string, IEnumerable<XDocument>>> x = myList.Select(group => Tuple.Create(group.Key, group.Select(tuple => tuple.Item2)))`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create your own `IGrouping<>` implementation, something like this would work:

```
public class Grouping<TKey, TElement>
    : IGrouping<TKey, TElement>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<TElement> elements;

    public Grouping(TKey key, IEnumerable<TElement> elements)
    {
        this.elements = elements;
        Key = key;
    }

    public TKey Key { get; }

    public IEnumerator<TElement> GetEnumerator() => elements.GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => elements.GetEnumerator();
}
```

Then to convert the `IGrouping<>` do something like this:

```
IGrouping<string, XDocument> newGrouping = new Grouping<string, XDocument>(
    oldGrouping.Key,
    oldGrouping.Select(x => x.Item2));
```

If you have an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<>>` then just do the same thing inside a select:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, XDocument>> newGroupings = oldGroupings
    .Select(x => new Grouping<string, XDocument>(x.Key, x.Select(y => y.Item2)));
```

Based on question updates, keeping your original IGroupings and without implementing your own IGrouping is possible with:

```
yourGroupings
    .SelectMany(x => x)
    .GroupBy(x => GetSomePropertyToGroupBy(x.Item2), x => x.Item2);
```

Comment: That grouping is created in a seperate class that I don't have accesss to. I'm trying to modify the given group.

Comment: Updated again; last answer keeps your original IGroupings and is shortest, but a lot less inefficient than creating your own IGrouping implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I modified like this

```
foreach (var crewKey in crew.GroupBy(x=>x.CrewId))
                {
                key.AsEnumerable().ToList().First().CrewWorkers = key.Select(x => new CrewWorker() { 
                    EmployeeId = x.EmployeeId, IsDeleted = x.IsDeleted }).ToList();
```